# Inherited control designer view

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

When I inherit a standard user control, say TextBox, I expect to view it in the same (default) way in the designer view. The .designer.vb code:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class ASearchBox
    Inherits TextBox

'UserControl overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    'Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
End Sub

End Class
```

The "Designer View" (NOT what I want, I'd like a default TextBox so I see the properties changes "live" without running the program):

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you create a new UserControl, then replaced `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` with `Inherits TextBox`? A TextBox is not a UserControl (i.e. a ContainerControl) and it doesn't have a `UserControlDocumentDesigner` or `ScrollableControlDesigner`. Do you want to build a UserControl that contains a TextBox, or a Custom Control derived from the TextBox Control? In both cases, you don't need to *run the Program* to see *properties changes*.

Comment: @Jimi I did that, yes. I want to build a Custom Control, derived from the TextBox control. I want to edit and see the default control without dragging an instance of it on a form.

Comment: Well, you cannot do that. Controls don't have a visual Designer. I don't see the problem, add your custom TextBox (BTW, don't use the UserControl construct to build it, just an empty class that `Inherits TextBox`) to a Form or UserControl (containers that have a visual Designer). If you change something (that is not subject to serialization), rebuild the project, otherwise remove the old instance and place a new one on a Container. You could also use a UserControl that only contains a TextBox and auto-sizes to it.

Comment: @Jimi ok, thanks a lot for the clarification. The "problem" is that that way I can't use smart tags (using Telerik's RadButtonTextBox) but yeah, it's not really a big deal...